# Use .htaccess to block all domains to access images folder except myown domain

Tags: .htaccess

i want to use .htacess to block all domains to access my images folder.
this folder is only accessible by own domain only.

Comment: Have you got any existing .htaccess we can look at?

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is some sort of hotlink protection in which case this in your .htaccess file should work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?yourdomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ - [NC,F,L]
```

Change yourdomain.com to whatever your domain is. Change the RewriteRule to include any file extensions you wish to block and then place the entire thing in a .htaccess file in the directory you wish to protect.

Comment: i give it a try and let you know

Answer (score 2):

As described in [this page of Apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/access.html#blocked-inline-images), you can accomplish it with the following directives, replacing `example\.com` with your domain name (please remember to escape any dot characters from `.` to `\.`:

```
SetEnvIf Referer example\.com localreferer
<FilesMatch \.(jpe?g|png|gif)$>
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from env=localreferer
</FilesMatch>
```