# htaccess - Deny requests from unauthorized domains

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a website "www.mysite.com", and it has an its own ip. Now since few months I see several domains pointing to my ip server (it's not a shared ip). I can navigate thru the entire website with those unauthorized domains, they get indexed in google with my contents and all.

How can i set my htaccess to allow requests only for "www.mysite.com" ?

**UPDATE**

this is the .htaccess I've written so far with the suggestions, but somehow the first page is still served, with no images tho

.htaccess

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer "^http://(www.)?thiefdomain.com" spam_ref  
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer "^http://(www.)?thiefdomain2.com" spam_ref2


<FilesMatch "(.*)">  
    Order Allow,Deny  
    Allow from all  
    Deny from env=spam_ref  
    Deny from env=spam_ref2  
</FilesMatch>  

RewriteEngine On  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d  
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]  
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

How can I avoid the first page to be displayed?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to do with mod_rewrite, you can check `SERVER_NAME` to block unauthorized domains:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^(www\.)?thiefdomain1\.example$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^(www\.)?thiefdomain2\.example$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^(www\.)?thiefdomain3\.example$
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

or

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} !^(www\.)?yourdomain\.example$
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} !^(www\.)?yourdomain-alias\.example$
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

---

If you have root privileges, you can also solve the problem with name-based virtual hosting as follows:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost 192.0.2.100:80>
  ServerName dummy
  <Location />
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
  </Location>
  ...
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 192.0.2.100:80>
  ServerName www.yourdomain.example
  ServerAlias yourdomain.example
  ...
</VirtualHost>
```

The first `VirtualHost` definition is treated as a **default** virtual host.  If 192.0.2.100 is accessed as thiefdomain1.example, thiefdomain2.example, thiefdomain3.example, or any other hostnames except  for www.yourdomain.example or yourdomain.example (defined in the second `VirtualHost`), Apache refers the first `VirtualHost` and returns 403 Forbidden status.

Comment: Will these affect html link tags? like for example if other site has a `<a href="mysite.com">Link</a>` will the above code block access to them?

Comment: Thanks a lot! Found another domain pretty much stealing my site and displaying it in his domain.

Comment: You're a hero!!

Answer (score 0):

<strike>1) What IPs are your thieves coming from? Can you block those IPs?</strike>

2) Have you reported them to Google for content stealing (if you can prove you are the owner)?

3) Have you reported this to the domain hoster? (e.g. GoDaddy)

4) You can also rewrite your HTML so they are absolute paths instead of relative:

For example, a relative path would look like:

```
< a href="/page/2.html">page 2</a>
```

absolute path would include your web site address:

```
<a href="http://www.site.com/page/2.html">page 2</a>
```

Comment: 1) there's no ip to block, they just associate their domains to my ip
2) I have reported it, but then they change the domain and I have to start over
4) I can, but it would be extremely painful to change all my application links to absolute ones, and it wouldn't resolve the issue for the homepage

Comment: Could you put code in your pages to perform a 301 redirect to your domain if IP or domain being referenced is not yours? http://www.phpjunkyard.com/tutorials/php-redirect.php

Comment: This would work, but I wonder if there's a way to accomplish that with Apache, it makes me wonder how could I do that if my website was in plain HTML

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6340203/use-htaccess-to-block-all-domains-to-access-images-folder-except-myown-domain

Comment: Thank you, I've adapted it to my needs and it works, but still display the very first page. Updated my question with the code

Answer (score -5):

I can't say particularly for htaccess. but through programming, you can achieve this.
say, your domain is www.mydomain.com. suppose the browser is requesting for about-me section of your web site. you can do the following. I'm showing for PHP(as I am little educated with php).

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == "your domain")
{
//show content
}
else
{
echo "your are not authorized to view contents from here.";
}
```

if u prefer other languages, they might have their way to get the host name.